# React MapBox I can't change location

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I am using alex3165/react-mapbox-gl and I have a problem. I'm trying to see x,y location but it isn't change. Constantly showing London. I also tried changing the node_module but result is the same. What should I do?

```
const coordinate=[29.371532589441756,40.896189603433761];

return (
  <div>
      <div className="col-md-7 col-xs-12">
          <div id="map" className="map-sm">
              <Map
                  style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9"
                  zoom={zoom}
                  containerStyle={{
                  height: "100%",
                  width: "100%",
                  center: {position}

                  }}>
                  <Layer
                      type="symbol"
                      id="marker"
                      layout={{ "icon-image": "marker-15" }}>

                  </Layer>
                  <Feature coordinates={coordinate}/>
              </Map>
          </div>
```

Comment: Hi there, you can use some of the map methods to programatically change your center position, see : https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#easeto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `center` attribute on the `Map` Component. You're just setting a feature to be displayed on the map by using the `Feature` component, this does not actually set the default position for MapBox.

```
<Map
    style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9"
    zoom={zoom}
    containerStyle={{
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
    }}
    center={coordinate}
>
    <Layer
        type="symbol"
        id="marker"
        layout={{ "icon-image": "marker-15" }}>

    </Layer>
    <Feature coordinates={coordinate}/>
</Map>
```